# MySQL - Mapping user username to user's ID in a query

Tags: sql, mysql

I've done some complex SQL queries, but never joined two tables by multiple values, and im not sure is it is possible.

I've the following two tables:

```
        users
        +-------+----------+
        | u_ID  | username |
        +-------+----------+
        |   1   |  Pablo   |
        +-------+----------+
        |   2   |   Mike   |
        +-------+----------+


        Messages
        +-------+----------+---------+
        | m_ID  | auhor_id | message |
        +-------+----------+---------+
        |   1   |     2    | Heelo5  |
        +-------+----------+---------+
        |   2   |     1    | he4532  |
        +-------+----------+---------+
        |   3   |     2    | he4111  |
        +-------+----------+---------+
        |   4   |     1    | he4538  |
        +-------+----------+---------+
```

What SQL query will i need to get this table?

```
    +-------+----------+---------+
    | m_ID  | username | message |
    +-------+----------+---------+
    |   1   |   Mike   | Heelo5  |
    +-------+----------+---------+
    |   2   |  Pablo   | he4532  |
    +-------+----------+---------+
    |   3   |   Mike   | he4111  |
    +-------+----------+---------+
    |   4   |  Pablo   | he4538  |
    +-------+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select m.m_ID, u.username, m.message
from Messages m, users u
where m. auhor_id = u.m_ID;
```

Probably you want additional conditions in the WHERE clause to specify which *Messages* records.  As I've written it, all messages records are displayed.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i need to get started i handle the other conditions, i just wanted to made the example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
 m.m_ID,
 u.username,
 m.message
from
 users u
inner join messages m on u.u_ID = m.author_id
order by
 m.m_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.m_ID, u.username, m.message 
from messages m inner join users u on u.u_ID = m.auhor_id
```